# Library Web Part - "Move to" action - Where Is it?

Tags: sharepoint-online, web-part

I would like to understand how is it that I can enable, in a "Document Library" web part - all the commands available in the standalone library view.

I cannot understand why is it that I just don't have things like "Copy to" or "Move to" available in the command bar. Those are such basic operations.

I do have them available if I go into the standalone document library view but I find that extra click and context change for a user to be unproductive.

Is there any way to customize what commands are availabile in the Document Library web part?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For it is by-design to show these commands in the command bar in web part. You can post your idea in [User Voice](https://sharepoint.uservoice.com/) and let MS know the thoughts.

Answer (score 0):

By design, SharePoint Online Library has "**Move to**" and "**Copy to**" action in the command bar. **But this depends on your permissions**:

[image]

- To **Copy**, you will need **at least “Add” permissions** in the
  target site. You will be adding documents, so you will need
  Contribute, Edit or Full Control or similar.**“Read” permissions** to
  the source site are sufficient in order to be able to Copy content.
- To **Move**, you will need **at least “Add” permissions** in the
  target site AND **“Delete” permissions** in the source site, as Move
  deletes the documents in the source site.

[image]

Comment: Thank you but Jerry responded to my question. it's about having the "move to" command available in the web part. I know it is available, granted permissions, in the "normal" view of a library.

Comment: Hi, Razvan Costea-Barlutiu. Thanks for your reply. Have a nice day!